# Can this post be un-community wiki-ed?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-answer, community-wiki

Bit of a boring one, this one.

As per [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status) can a moderator please change [this post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/176600/64888) back to a Dark Lord post from a community wiki?

I'm on mobile and I simply pressed the wrong button. I assumed I'd be able to edit a reverse but apparently not.

Don't anybody dare suggest that 'un-community wiki' is not a verb.

Answer (score 7):

### Done.

<sub>But just FYI, flagging is probably a quicker way to go about this than a meta post. Moderators do follow meta, but raising a custom flag is the best way to contact mods specifically, and nobody else reading meta can really help you here.</sub>

Comment: Ok, thanks, Rand and also @Mooz for your help

Comment: @TheDarkLord I made sure to un-CW-ify it *before* upvoting it, so that you'd still get the rep from that upvote ;-)